# How to increase the sound quality and loudness on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound

I have a ThinkPad e14 and the sound quality is way better on Windows 11. This may be because of Dolby but loudness is also very low in Ubuntu.

How to improve the loudness and sound quality to make it feel like windows?

Comment: Try to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en). It was useful for me to activate Settings -> Sound -> Over-Amplification

Comment: Volume increased but the quality is disaster.